# In Python, is there a way to detect if any other window is maximized or not? [Windows 10]

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a python tkinter application which always stays on the desktop. To do this, I need to check whether any other window is maximized or not, similar to `WS_MAXIMIZE` in Visual Basic .NET, or GetWindowPlacement API. Is there any way to do this?

Looking forward to your replies!

Comment: Why don't you just make your window the top-most window?

Comment: @acw1668, I don't want it to be on top all the time. When another window is opened, I want it to minimize.

Comment: Then call `deiconify()` when `<FocusIn>` and `iconify()` when `<FocusOut>`.

Comment: @acw1668 this would work if my window didn't show up on the taskbar because I used the `overrideredirect` method. It will still be hidden if I use Win+D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pip install pygetwindow` to get `pygetwindow`

```
import pygetwindow as gw
notepadWindow = gw.getWindowsWithTitle('Untitled')[0]
notepadWindow.isMaximized
```

Here I have a notepad open and am checking if it is maximised or minimsed!

Documentation for help: https://pypi.org/project/PyGetWindow/